# Stop retries in Android WebView HTTP Authentification

Tags: android, webview, raspberry-pi3, http-authentication

I have a WebView in my Android app which loads a webpage from my raspberry pi. This webpage is protected by Basic Authentification.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
        handler.proceed(user, pass);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
        super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
// I'm always landing here if authentification fails.
    }
});

webView.loadUrl(protocol + "://" + hostname + ":" + port);
```

How can I stop retries if the authentification fails? If I don't stop this, the app sends a request every second until I close the app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
  webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        int tries = 0;

        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
            handler.proceed(user, pass);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
            super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);

            if (tries > 1) {
                webView.destroy();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorResponse.getStatusCode() + ": "
                        + errorResponse.getReasonPhrase(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            tries++;
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl(protocol + "://" + hostname + ":" + port);
```